# Is the Williams contract question an allowable sports trivia example?

Tags: discussion

There's been [one discussion](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23/should-we-allow-sports-trivia) in Sports.meta regarding sports trivia. I noticed a recent question about [Ted William's largest contract](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/493/what-was-ted-williams-highest-grossing-contract). It's admittedly not a great question, but seems to fall under the category of sports trivia.

Should this question be rejected as being off-topic, or allowed with a trivia tag? There have already been some votes to close - it'd be good to see how the community feels about trivia questions in general.

Comment: the correct close reason here is not constructive.

Comment: [Yes](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/260/sports-trivia-evaluation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Its a general reference question that can be answered in 2 second on Google (first link gives a full history).

These kinds of questions are discouraged across the network as poor examples of expert Q&A.

I am not opposed to trivia questions in general, however they should be sufficiently obscure that they merit more than copy/pasting the first site that comes up on Google. They need an angle that makes them expert Q&A.

Comment: I tend to be quite conservative with general reference after some debate about it on scifi, but this is one I wouldn't hesitate to close as general reference.

Comment: @Kevin to be fair, there are many more sites devoted to sports general reference to be accessed via "I'm Feeling Lucky" than there are for sci-fi.

Comment: @corsiKa My position has nothing to do with the availability of information (and you might be surprised at the availability of scifi trivia). The relevant SFF questions were interesting, and had interesting answers.  This is at best a boring question with a boring answer that could easily have been retyped or copied and pasted from any of millions of websites, books, reference materials, etc. It is as banal as trivia can get.

Comment: @Kevin 100% agree on this question. All I was saying was that if you operate under the assumption that there are more sports trivia sites than scifi, then your bar for what you accept for trivia questions is even higher, as there's a higher likelihood the question should have been answered during the preliminary research stage. I don't disagree with your assessment of this question at all.