# Sports Trivia Evaluation

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

Personally, I have been iffy, at best, about sports trivia questions. However, I would rather reflect the perspective of the community than my own.

Take a look at the following sports trivia questions below. If you agree that the question is a good fit for this site, please upvote. If you feel the question wouldn't be a good fit, please downvote. With all questions, a comment about how and why it would fit or not is much appreciated.

***Sports Trivia** has been addressed in a [meta question](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23/should-we-allow-sports-trivia). This evaluation is extending that previous discussion.

Comment: The community has spoken. Sports Trivia is a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 3):

[Winning despite walking](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/790/winning-despite-walking)

What is the MLB record for the most walks (bases on balls) allowed in a single game (9 inning game) by a pitcher who ultimately still recorded the win?

Answer (score 2):

[MLB near perfect game](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/786/mlb-near-perfect-game)

To throw a perfect game a pitcher would have to get 27 batters out in a row.

How many times in MLB history has a pitcher had 26 strait outs only to allow the would be final batter to reach base?

Answer (score 2):

[Expo who remained longest with the Nationals](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/752/expo-who-remained-longest-with-the-nationals)

Which Expo player who moved to the Nationals in 2005 remained longest (continuously) with the Nationals?

Answer (score 2):

[NBA MVP/Finals MVP and Champion](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1220/nba-mvp-finals-mvp-and-champion)

So LeBron just won the title, the NBA MVP and NBA Finals MVP. Who else has done that? I know that generally the NBA Finals MVP belongs to the team that won the title, but I believe there was an instance where that didn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

[Is there NBA player who won triple MVP in one season?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/is-there-nba-player-who-won-triple-mvp-in-one-season)

Is there NBA player who won the all 3 NBA MVP awards?

this includes Regular Season MVP, Finals MVP and All-Star MVP award in the same season?