# Are quiz questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, asking-questions

In regards to this question: [image: http://sports.stackexchange.com/q/4065/527]

**Regardless of quality**, it is clear what the OP is asking and it is not opinion-based. Moreover, Sports SE has chosen to allow [trivia content](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23/should-we-allow-sports-trivia/31#31).

Given the community response (to which I agree with), it is apparent that quiz-questions need addressed.

**Are quiz questions on-topic?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Objective* questions about sports are on topic.

Good questions have long answers though, and that question...well that question looks like a sports proficiency quiz from a HS PE class.

That's not what we're here for, we're here to *learn about sports* and that question doesn't aid that goal.

Asking which one of these things is not like the other is...not interesting.

Comment: Agreed. I only ask to address the scenario, and to argue that "unclear what is being asked" and "opinion-based" doesn't really fit why the question is off topic. "Very low quality" or "apparent lack of research" is more in line in regards to why the question is off topic.

Answer (score 4):

When we say trivia content is allowed, what we mean is that we allow questions that discuss issues that are relatively unimportant to the participation or enjoyment of the sport.  For example, here is a recent question about trivia:

[Olympic medalist in both the Summer and Winter Olympics](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/3938/1723)

The answer doesn't really affect anyone who wants to enjoy watching or participating in the Olympics, but it is interesting information anyway.

That's not the same as a quiz question.  If the question had been asked like this, it should have been voted out of existence:

> Which of the following athletes has won a medal in both the Summer and Winter Olympics:
>
> A. Michael Jordan
>
> B. Brett Favre
>
> C. Goofy
>
> D. Clara Hughes

We don't play multiple choice games here.  As far as I know, this kind of question wouldn't be allowed on any StackExchange site.

Comment: +1. If Goofy ever makes Olympic appearances, he might have a chance :P

Comment: Which of the following SO users have beat themselves in the rep leagues?  **a)** Jon Skeet  **b)** Jon Skeet  **c)** Jon Skeet  **d)** Jeff Atwood