# What is the consensus on "do-it-for-me" questions?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

[This question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/20958/what-are-the-top-5-lowest-scoring-super-bowls) had the following comment:

> This is really a do-it-for-me question. You can easily find it out by yourself.

After seeing this comment, I feel like this has been happening occasionally. I recall a question being referred to as "b*tch work."

A second comment was also present:

> The vast majority of your questions are in this vein. This exchange should not be an Easter Egg hunt for your benefit. This site is more aimed at how sports work, or explaining why a particular play was executed as it was. Not for you to think up trivial quests.

What is the consensus on "do it for me" questions? Is this the correct way to categorize these type of questions? If it is worth addressing, I am looking with respect to the possibility of a similar type of question coming up with a similar comment to address its characteristic (ie, "do-it-for-me", etc.).

Previous discussions on the topic of trivia-type questions:

- [Should we allow sports trivia?](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23/should-we-allow-sports-trivia)
- [Trivia question on sports players: revisiting the issue](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/684/trivia-question-on-sports-players-revisiting-the-issue)
- [Sports Trivia Evaluation](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260/sports-trivia-evaluation)

Comment: The point of my question wasn't to get somebody else to give me the answer. In fact I was able to find the answer myself very easy, doesn't mean I need others to find it for me. B*tch work would be more like getting someone to spend hours to find you an answer you don't want to dig up yourself. The point of the question was to enhance our library of sports questions/answers/knowledge.

Comment: I could also answer the question myself, but I feel like that should only be done when a question goes unanswered for a long time, to allow other users answer and gain points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion, questions like that should stay. Only because they're easy to answer doesn't mean they're of low quality.

There are a lot of questions that can easily be searched on the internet, but where would you draw the line? Is this question too trivial just for you or does someone else maybe have difficulty finding the answer? Why forcing users to search for answers when they can easily be found here? Isn't that what Stack Exchange is about? Providing answers to your questions?

If you would disallow those "do-it-for-me" questions you could as well disallow most of the questions about rules. After all, there are official rule books which everyone can read.

I'm completely on alamoot's side. Sports.SE needs questions (and answers) and as long as we're low on both we shouldn't be too picky. Of course we need a fair standard, but as long as the question isn't of too low quality - keep it.

Answer (score 5):

I came across the following question: [Rules questions with "little" effort. Do we close these questions as off-topic or downvote?](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/661)

It looks like this has been a point of contention in the past, with the consensus being that these type of questions are allowed here.

The accepted answer states:

> If you think a question is too easy to waste your time answering, then
>   don't. If you don't think a question is an asset to the site, but it
>   doesn't match any of the close reasons, then downvote and move on. But
>   you don't need to prevent others from taking the time to write a great
>   answer and making the internet a better place. Then, when others do
>   try to google the same question, they will land here. That would be a
>   great thing for our site.

I find the quasi-persistent commenting about "you can do it yourself" and similar phrases to bring unwanted and unneeded noise to these types of questions and to this site in general.

Answer (score 3):

Piling on I suppose, but [the question referenced above](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/20958/what-are-the-top-5-lowest-scoring-super-bowls) is nice because I sometimes browse the site for questions of interest.  Now that the referenced question has been posted I guess I *am* curious what other low-scoring big games have occurred in the past and where the most recent event fits historically.

Comment: Thanks for your perspective. For all the "piling on" on this question and the question I reference in my answer, I'm surprised there are still negative comments floating around about these type of questions. One of the other answers in the question I reference shed light on how one user was very welcomed and the other user was very unwelcomed. I think "downvote and move on" is an effective way to get the point across without causing contention, especially since the matter has already been addressed.