# Why so many 'bar bet' questions?

Tags: discussion

It seems to me (and I admit, I may be wrong) that a large percentage of our questions are what I would call 'bar bet' questions. Some examples would be:

- [How many goalkeepers scored goals in the old First Division?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/25941/how-many-goalkeepers-scored-goals-in-the-old-first-division)
- [How many Africans have won the UEFA Champions League?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/20736/how-many-africans-have-won-the-uefa-champions-league)
- [What NBA players have won both Defensive Player of the Year and Most Valuable Player?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/20752/what-nba-players-have-won-both-defensive-player-of-the-year-and-most-valuable-pl)
- [Footballers with most free kicks scored](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/20339/footballers-with-most-free-kicks-scored)
- [What is the longest streak of a team being in playoffs, and what is the current ongoing streak?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/25913/what-is-the-longest-streak-of-a-team-being-in-playoffs-and-what-is-the-current)
- [How many bunt home runs has there been in the history of MLB?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/16447/how-many-bunt-home-runs-has-there-been-in-the-history-of-mlb)

There are and have been many, many, MANY others of this type. Of them, a large percentage are related to Football (soccer). They are mostly all relatively simple record book look ups.

There is nothing in [help/on-topic] or [help/dont-ask] either specifically allowing, or denying them, but within the **Some kinds of questions to NOT ask** is *Requests for sources/research* which these implicitly are (research).

Do we want to continue to embrace these types of questions?

Comment: [Should we allow sports trivia?](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23/should-we-allow-sports-trivia) is pretty similar to this; that is 9 years old though so we are always open to a new discussion on the community consensus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My general feeling on these are that they're fine, mostly because they're oftentimes the most interesting questions we have... but they're definitely something that can vary as far as quality.

I'm not sure "request for resources/research" is necessarily something we should keep in the "don't ask" anymore, to be honest; in the modern day, sports is very much about information/data science, and I can imagine perfectly reasonable questions asking about where sports information is kept (in particular, where *official* information resides).  I know that's a bit against how SE works to some extent - but I just don't see it as a problem in this particular space.

Of course, a question that's basically a "bar bet" as you say will often not get an answer, and I think that's okay - I answer the ones that I have expertise in and find interesting, and the same for others I'm sure, and the uninteresting ones can go unanswered.

That said, there are some I'd probably tend to close, if they're something that's too obscure to have any sort of relevance - all of the above seem at least okay to me, but something like "Who was the first player born on a Tuesday in June to score the third goal in a ..." probably is not a good question and should be closed.